# I am unsure of whether to use singular or plural describing a list where the objects in the list are choices

Tags: grammatical-number, lists

Which is correct:

> Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced **in *a* ratio** of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

or

> Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced **in ratio*s*** of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

Comment: I can see a case for using either. I think that you probably need a rewrite to make it absolutely clear what you are saying. One possibility is to add an extra "or", e.g., " Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced in a ratio/ratios of 1:2, ***or*** 1:1, ***or*** 2:1.   One problem I have is that you don't give a complete sentence or any proper context so I don't actually know what you are trying to say.  Are you trying all the strategies at some time or are you choosing just one to try?

Comment: Singular doesn't sound *outrageously* incorrect to me, but I'm not keen on it. I see there are about a dozen hits in Google Books for [*in **sizes** small medium and large*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+sizes+small+medium+and+large%22), but ***no relevant hits*** for singular [*in **size** small medium and large.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+size+small+medium+and+large%22&safe=strict&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03D2aVA_YpXtWyW5ARwQNP1P_JsSQ:1594116682819&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVnfC087rqAhX9QEEAHRdYCqEQpwUIIQ&biw=1342&bih=773&dpr=1.13)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. re: Chasly: each strategy is implemented and investigated.

Comment: X and Y are produced using three different strategies, A, B, and C; these produce X and Y in the ratios of 1:2, 1:1, and 2:1 respectively.

Comment: It's ratios.  "... X and Y are produced in ratios of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1." Agree with @EdwinAshworth

Answer (score 2):

To me they mean different things:

> Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced in a ratio of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

X and Y are separate products made of A and B. The ratio refers to the A:B relationship.

> Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced in ratios of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

X and Y are the components of a single product. “Ratios” refers to the X:Y relationship.

---

Here is another phrasing that may be closer to the intended meaning:

> Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced in  a ratio of **either** 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

X and Y are separate products that occur or are produced as a result of the variables of a system.

Answer (score -1):

First, if those are sentences, neither of them is correct. They are both sentence fragments.

Look at the essential component of the sentence:

> ？ Three different strategies whereby X and Y are produced.

That's syntactically the same as the following:

> ？ Three different people who walk down the street.

Both of those are noun phrases, but there is no main verb. What do the strategies do? What do the people do?

---

That aside, the question doesn't make it clear if each strategy produces X and Y in a *different* ratio, or if they simply produce X and Y in a ratio that matches one or more of the three ratios.

Possible wordings include the following:

- **Each** of the three strategies **produces** X and Y in a **unique** ratio of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.
- **Each** of the three strategies **produces** X and Y in a ratio of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.
- The three strategies **respectively produce** X and Y in ratios of 1:2, 1:1, **and** 2:1.
- The three strategies **produce** X and Y in a ratio of 1:2, 1:1, or 2:1.

Note the switch from the indefinite article to the definite article in the one case, because all three are described at once, and each must use a unique ratio.

Comment: OP doesn't say they are sentences. They could be titles.